# How to use VkPipelineCache?

Tags: vulkan

If I understand it correctly, I'm supposed to create an empty `VkPipelineCache` object, pass it into `vkCreateGraphicsPipelines`and data will be written into it. I can then reuse it with other pipelines I'm creating or save it to a file and use it on the next run.

I've tried following the LunarG example to extra the info:

```
uint32_t headerLength = pData[0];
uint32_t cacheHeaderVersion = pData[1];
uint32_t vendorID = pData[2];
uint32_t deviceID = pData[3];
```

But I always get `headerLength` is 32 and the rest 0. Looking at the spec (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.0.26.0/linux/vkspec.chunked/ch09s06.html Table 9.1), the cacheHeaderVersion should always be 1, as the only available cache header version is `VK_PIPELINE_CACHE_HEADER_VERSION_ONE = 1`.

Also the size of pData is usually only 32 bytes, even when I create 10 pipelines with it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

A Vulkan pipeline cache is an *opaque* object that's only meaningful to the driver.  There are *very few* operations that you're supposed to use on it.

- [Creating a pipeline cache](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/man/html/vkCreatePipelineCache.html), optionally with a block of opaque binary data that was saved from an earlier run
- [Getting the opaque binary data from an existing pipeline cache](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/man/html/vkGetPipelineCacheData.html), typically to serialize to disk before exiting your application
- [Destroying a pipeline cache](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/man/html/vkDestroyPipelineCache.html) as part of the proper shutdown process.

The idea is that the driver can use the cache to speed up creation of pipelines within your program, and also to speed up pipeline creation on subsequent runs of your application.

You should not be attempting to interpret the cache data returned from `vkGetPipelineCacheData` *at all*.  The only purpose for that data is to be passed into a later call to `vkCreatePipelineCache`.

> Also the size of pData is usually only 32 bytes, even when I create 10 pipelines with it. What am I doing wrong?

Drivers **must** implement `vkCreatePipelineCache`, `vkGetPipelineCacheData`, etc.  But they don't actually have to support caching.  So if you're working with a driver that doesn't have anything it can cache, or hasn't done the work to support caching, then you'd naturally get back an empty cache (other than the header).

Comment: First 32 bits do give your application information, LunarG has an example: https://github.com/LunarG/VulkanSamples/blob/master/API-Samples/pipeline_cache/pipeline_cache.cpp

Comment: @RhuMage Do you think there is something inadequate about this answer?

Comment: @opa Well my question wasn't answered. Why are my values 0 and why is there no other data? I create 10 pipelines with a cache and the only thing I get out of it is the empty header, no actual cache data.

Comment: @Jherico I agree with Rhu Mage, what ever the standard says, it doesn't make sense that a pipeline cache is completely empty.  As it stands this answer, while it provides important information, doesn't help us understand what is going on here, is Rhu Mage wrong in stating `cacheHeaderVersion` should always be 1?

Comment: @opa https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.0.26.0/linux/vkspec.chunked/ch09s06.html Table 9.1: a VkPipelineCacheHeaderVersion value, and the only one available is `VK_PIPELINE_CACHE_HEADER_VERSION_ONE = 1`

Comment: @RhuMage I would recommend sourcing that in your question

Comment: @Jherico I have the latest nVidia drivers. I've tried running Sascha Willems examples and I do get cache data there, but I can't find a difference between his code and mine.

Comment: I suggest you post a minimal example then.